# javascript stopPropagation not working on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a simple div array with values that the user will choose from and an "other" field where they can put in their own number. I have a clearing div (lower right) that will clear the selection and input field; however, I also want to have a click event on the containing div as well.

I've searched and nothing seems to do the trick, the one that comes close is using stopPropagation so the click on a div doesn't trigger the containing div's script. It's working on all the divs but for some reason isn't working on the input field. everytime i click the number scrubber or try typing in the field it calls the reset script of the containing div. Is there something about an input field that causes the stopPropagation to not work? or am i missing something. None of the other things i found seemed to solve it.

HTML

```
<div id="don_options">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">xxx</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <div class="col"><span class="don">Other</span><br class="mobile"><input id="other" name="other" type="number" min="3" step=".01" value="" size="25" maxlength="255" class="form-text2" placeholder="Other"></div>
        <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col"><span class="don">Clear</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#don_options').on('click', function(e) {
    resetDon();
});

$('.don').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop bubbling to parent element
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.cancelBubble = true;
    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    //lots of buttonesk goodness here
});

$('#other').on('keyup change click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop bubbling to parent element
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.cancelBubble = true;
    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    //more goodness here for the input field
});

function resetDon() {
    //clear "buttons" here
}
```

Adding a quick screenshot for visual. Black box is the containing div
[image]

Comment: If the change is caused by a click, since it is type number, your cancel would cancel the 'change' event that the click would cause, but not the 'click' event itself, as far as i am aware.

Comment: even clicking on the number scribber arrows too?

Comment: That's a click.  The event that you are handling for is either the keyup or change event.  That won't affect any other event that would normally be created.  You're stopping a -specific- event from bubbling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this code:

```
$('.don').on('click', function() {
   e.stopPropagation(); // stop bubbling to parent element
   ...
});
```

`e` is undefined. It should be the function parameter:

```
$('.don').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); // stop bubbling to parent element
   ...
});
```

See full docs for [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The event should be passed as parameter of the function (handler). Of course, you can skip it whenever you don't want to interact with it.

Comment: Something that would have been easily noticed in dev tools console error thrown

Comment: appologies, i do have the e inside the functions ...updated the question. it still doesn't work for the input field

Comment: @VikingNM, please update with a [mcve] (a live snippet - here or on jsFiddle). Also state in clear what you're expecting and when and I'll find a way to achieve it. Without a verifiable example, the task description is quite vague.

Comment: @VikingNM As you can see in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/L5uhma3o/), where I colored all elements that have bubbling disabled, it works fine. Please update it to explain what you are trying to achieve and how it fails in your case.